# Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a metrizable space. Prove that $X$ Lindelöf implies that $X$ is separable.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, separable-spaces, lindelof-spaces

> Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a metrizable space. Prove that $X$ Lindelöf
>   implies that $X$ is separable.

**My attempt**:

Let $d$ be the metric that induces the topology $\mathcal{T}$.

For every $n \geq 1$, consider the open cover: $$\{B_X(x,1/n)\mid x \in X\}$$

Because the space is Lindelöf, this implies that for every $n \geq 1$, there is a countable (or finite) subcover given by $$\mathcal{B}_n:= \{B_X(x,1/n) \mid x \in I_n, |I_n| \leq |\mathbb{N}|\}$$

Now, define $D:= \bigcup_{n\geq 1} I_n$. Let $y \in X$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $m$ a positive integer so large that $1/m < \epsilon$.

Because $y\in X =\bigcup\mathcal{B}_m$, it follows that there exists $x \in D$ such that $y \in B_X(x,1/m)$, meaning that $d(x,y) < 1/m < \epsilon$, such that $x \in B_X(y, \epsilon) \cap D$. Hence, $y \in \overline{D}$ and it follows that $D$ is a dense countable set in $X$, such that $X$ is separable.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is almost exactly as I would prove it too. Alternatively we could show that $(X,d)$ is second countable first e.g., it really does not matter all that much. See my [answer here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2004;task=show_msg;msg=0570.0001) for a general statement.