# Is every sigma-compact space is lindelof space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is every sigma-compact topological  space is Lindelof space ?
I know about $\sigma$-compact and Lindelof space.Say about converse is true or not.

Comment: How to prove that every sigma-compact space is Lindelof space

Comment: Every open cover of the space has a finite subcover on each compact. Take the countable union and you get a countable subcover.

Comment: If you have a proof please share with me.

Comment: Even every sigma-Lindelöf space is Lindelöf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $X= \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} K_n$ where each $K_n$ is compact.

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be any open cover of $X$.

We have for each $n$ that $K_n \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{U}$ so there is a finite subcover $\mathcal{U}_n \subseteq \mathcal{U}$ such that $K_n \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{U}_n$ as $K_n$ is compact.

Then $\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \mathcal{U}_n$ is a *countable* (a countable union of finite sets is countable) subcover of $\mathcal{U}$.

As $\mathcal{U}$ was arbitrary, $X$ is Lindelöf.

Comment: Thank you sir....